# how to write a mock data for getting the value from service in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

i have a customer details like customerName i have to use that in 2 pages so am using getter and setter in service file, i set the customerName in service(component 1) and getting it in where ever need (component 2) facing error while writing test case (component 2) for  getting the value (in component 2)

i have tried like below

```
const customerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('customerService', ['getCustomerName', 'setCustomerName']);


it('should tests save customer name function', () => {
      customerSpy.setCustomerName('xxx'); - I have tried to adding like this
        let response = {
            'response': 'success'
        };
        customerSpy.saveCustomerName.and.returnValue(of(response));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.saveCustomerName();
    });
```

Spec file:

```
const customerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('customerService', ['getCustomerName', 'setCustomerName', 'saveCustomerName']);

it('should tests save customer name function', () => {

        let response = {
            'response': 'success'
        };
        customerSpy.saveCustomerName.and.returnValue(of(response));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.saveCustomerName();
    });
```

component code:

component 1:

```
public dummyFunc(){
  this.customerService.setCustomerName('xxx');
}
```

component 2:

```
public saveCustomerName() {
    let name = this.customerService.getCustomerName();
    this.customerService.saveCustomerName(name).subscribe(
      (success) => {

      },
      (fail) => {
      }
    );
  }
```

while Running the testcase for component 2 i should get the customer name in component 2 to pass it to the mockservice

Comment: yes it worked thank you. sry for late reply

Comment: do you know how to write test case for ElementRef

Comment: Awesome ! Yeah, I think can help you with that. Let me know the question url, I'll try to answer. Feel free to upvote my answer as well. [Here](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7) is series of articles which can help you more to write better `karma` test cases. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to worry about `component1` when you are testing `component2`.You can isolate it for below function as :

```
public saveCustomerName() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    let name = this.customerService.getCustomerName();
    this.customerService.saveCustomerName(name).subscribe(
      (success) => {
        this.showSpinner = false; // or something similar variable assignment.
      },
      (fail) => {
      }
    );
  }
```

and in spec file:

```
it('should set customer name on calling function "saveCustomerName()"', () => {
   spyOn(component.customerService,'getCustomerName').and.returnValue('testName');
   spyOn(component.customerService,'saveCustomerName').and.returnValue(of('saved'));
   component.showSpinner = true;
   component.saveCustomerName();
   expect(component.customerService.getCustomerName).toHaveBeenCalled();
   expect(component.customerService.saveCustomerName).toHaveBeenCalledWith('testName);
   expect(component.showSpinner).toBeFalsy();
});
```